# Julia: find out if run from REPL or command line

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to determine if a julia script `myprog.jl` has been invoked from the command line via `julia myprog.jl` or from the REPL via `include("myprog.jl")`?

Background: I'm using the [ArgParse.jl](https://github.com/carlobaldassi/ArgParse.jl) package and since I cannot pass command line arguments from the REPL, I want to just set a variable `ARGS = "argA --optB 1 --flagC"` prior to calling `include("myprog.jl")` in order to achieve the same result as `julia myprog.jl argA --optB 1 --flagC` from the command line. To do this I need to know if the program was called from the command line or from the REPL, such that I could just write something like

```
if called_from_repl
    parse_args(split(ARGS),s)
else
    parse_args(s)
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use `isinteractive` to determine whether Julia is running an interactive session.

Consider the example below (I use `$` for command line prompt and `julia>` for Julia REPL prompt)

```
$ more test.jl

println("interactive : $(isinteractive())")


$ julia test.jl
interactive : false
```

Now let us run the same script in the REPL:

```
julia> include("test.jl")
interactive : true
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. Base defines the constant `Base.PROGRAM_FILE` which contains script name passed on the command line. The macro `Base.@__FILE__` evaluates to the path of the script where this macro is called.

The expression `abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__` evaluates to true in the script passed on the command line, but false for included scripts.

This technique is discussed in the Julia Lang documentation: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/faq/#man-scripting-1